# Cuda kernel configuration

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm writing a cuda c code to process pictures for example i created a swap function (swap blocs of the matrix) but it dos not work every time i thing i have a problem with the number of blocs and number of threads whene i lunch my kernel.

For example if i tak an image of size 2048*2048 with

`threadsPerBlock.x=threadsPerBlock.y=64` and `numBlocks.x=numBlocks.y=2048/threadsPerBlock.x`

then `swap<<<threadsPerBlock,numBlocks>>>(...)` works fine.

But if I take an image of size 2560*2160, `threadsPerBlock.x=threadsPerBlock.y=64` and `numBlocks.x=2560/64` and `numBlocks.y=2160/64+1`, I have an error 9 wish is error invalid configuration argument.

I'm using CUDA 7.5 and a GPU with compute capability 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [maximum number of threads per block for your compute 5.0](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications) device is 1024. The source of your problem is that you have the arguments in the kernel launch reversed. When the maximum dimension of the image is less than 2048, that gives you a launch with less than 1024 threads per block. Larger than 2048 and the block size becomes illegal

If you do something like this:

```
threadsPerBlock.x=threadsPerBlock.y=32
numBlocks.x=numBlocks.y=2048/threadsPerBlock.x
swap<<<numBlocks,threadsPerBlock>>>(...)
```

You should find the kernel launch works unconditionally.

Comment: Yes i have a compute 5.0 but i have  Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64) i'm using 2Dim the problem i forgot to munchen it works for the size 2560*2160 with 256*256 block size at first i that may be i passed the number of blocs but it's not the case.

Comment: @SalahEddine: You are misunderstanding the block size limits. (Re)read the link in my answer. Maximum block dimensions are (1024,1024,64), but the *total number* of threads per block must be less than or equal to 1024, ie. only blocks with `dim.x*dim.y*dim.z <= 1024` are legal

Comment: Thnx a lot  talonmies that wase my problem :)